# Consolidating Click Functions & Scalability

Tags: javascript, jquery, scalability

How can I simplify and consolidate these two click functions into one, and make it scalable for future table row classes? My code works, but it's not very scalable.

See Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/49hvfdje/10/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style> .hidden { display: none; } </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.click.a').click(function() {
          $('tr.a').toggleClass('hidden'); // toggleClass for A rows
          return false;
        });

        $('a.click.b').click(function() {
          $('tr.b').toggleClass('hidden'); // toggleClass for B rows
          return false;
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr><td><a class='click a'>Toggle A Rows</a></td></tr>
        <tr class='hidden a'><td>Text</td></tr>
        <tr class='hidden a'><td>Text</td></tr>
        <tr class='hidden a'><td>Text</td></tr>

        <tr><td><a class='click b'>Toggle B Rows</a></td></tr>
        <tr class='hidden b'><td>Text</td></tr>
        <tr class='hidden b'><td>Text</td></tr>
        <tr class='hidden b'><td>Text</td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look into the [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/#closest1) or [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) functions in jQuery.

Comment: Could be a use-case for `data` attributes, ie `data-row-type="a"` on "a" rows, and `data-toggle-row="a"` on the `<a>` element that hides them. Then you can get the `data-toggle-row` value from the clicked element, and hide any elements on the page with a `data-row-type` that match it.

Comment: ^ Demo of what I described above: https://jsfiddle.net/49hvfdje/19/

Comment: @TylerRoper -- Thanks Tyler!